# Paypal return URL

Tags: php, ssl, ssl-certificate, paypal

I'm programming a PHP site with Paypal integration and I've stumbled into a problem with the return url. I need users to be returned back to a specific url on my site after in the final step. I have things in my session variables that need to be moved into a database.

The problem is, the Paypal secure form that has the "return" button is submitting to my site, which is not secure, so the web-browser complains with an SSL warning. This does not look at all good for my not so technical visitors who might suspect there is a security problem. Some may not even click to continue back to my site, which will be very bad as my db will not get updated.

I'm wondering what my options are here? Will that warning message disappear if I make the return pages use SSL?

Comment: Is it just me or should you perform the database update only when you get notified by PayPal about the transaction? That's a whole different thing...

Comment: I could do that. But I the way I've built this thing; I wouldn't be able to get access to the session variables when the notification php script is run.

Comment: This does give me an idea though.. I could store the session key in the Paypal notification URL and the retrieve the session variables from that script.

Comment: Yes, either append the session ID or put the order/invoice number in the invoice field when sending to paypal. Use one of these two identifiers in your notification script. Do NOT rely on the user coming back to your site to process the order.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Get an [SSL certificate](http://www.google.com/search?q=ssl+certificate) for your site and that error message will go away.